# Is it possible to "deep link" to a specific email in mail.app on Mac OS X?

Tags: email, links

For example, in a note-taking application like Evernote or an outliner, is it possible to create a link that will open a specific email in a specific folder in Mail.app on Max OS X?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what are you trying to achieve?
If you need to save a reference to a certain e-mail, then you can simply flag it by using flag button in the toolbar or by right-clicking the message and then find it by looking at Flagged category in the Mailboxes pane on the left.
Or you can drag-n-drop message anywhere else, including Evernote or desktop.
Could you, please, clarify?

Comment: @DenisRasulev: Elliott, below, gave a perfect answer, but I also want to give you credit for reminding me that it's possible to drag an email into Evernote, resulting in a link back to the email, rather than copying the whole email object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In OS X, you can use a URL of the format `message:<MESSAGE-ID>` to open the specific message in Mail.app.  So how do we find the message ID?  If the message includes a date or other "data detector", you can click the dotted line around that and add it to your calendar.  Then in Calendar.app, the newly created event will have a URL, which you can copy.

A more convenient way is to use AppleScript.  Run the following code when you have the message selected in Mail.  This will copy the URL to your clipboard.  There are various ways to set this up to run with a keyboard shortcut, etc.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set _sel to get selection
    set _links to {}
    repeat with _msg in _sel
        set _messageURL to "message://%3c" & _msg's message id & "%3e"
        set end of _links to _messageURL
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
    set the clipboard to (_links as string)
end tell
```

Note the angle brackets in this script are written as the URL encoded `%3c`.

Source: https://daringfireball.net/2007/12/message_urls_leopard_mail

Comment: The Message ID is also available from the Raw Source view in Mail.app (View -> Message -> Raw Source).  It is usually listed at the bottom of the email headers, typically of the form `Message-ID: <foo@bar.baz.com>`.  Copy the text after the colon, and use that as the ID to construct the message URI manually.  Not as convenient as the script, but less setup if you don't intend to do this a lot.

Comment: Thank you, @Elliott — this is exactly what I wanted. The AppleScript snippet was icing on the cake. I'll be setting up a Keyboard Maestro shortcut for it.