# Is it possible to create a link/URL to a particular mailbox folder in Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, url

I would like to link to a particular email folder so that when I click a URL file in Finder or URL link in another application (such as Notes), it opens the email folder in Mail for me.

Is this possible?

Three different questions already discuss creating a link/URL to a particular email message in Mail, but I want to link to the folder instead:

- [URL to individual email](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54969/url-to-individual-email)
- [Copy message_id from selected message](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54981/copy-message-id-from-selected-message)
- [Is it possible to "deep link" to a specific email in mail.app on Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300437/is-it-possible-to-deep-link-to-a-specific-email-in-mail-app-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: RE: "I would like to link to a particular email folder so that when I click it in Finder or another application" --  What exactly do you mean by "link" in the context of **Finder** and any other _application_?

Comment: I re-formed the question slightly. You know, be able to click a link and that opens a particular mailbox folder in Mail.